# Variavel em message box c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Como colocar uma variavel dentro da message box? O codigo vem abaixo acho que é auto explicativo.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace A12
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var c;
        c = 23;
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("{0}", c);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O codigo abaixo também é auto explicativo. :)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int _c;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _c = 23;
    }    

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("{0}", _c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Complementando um pouco a resposta do Thiago Lunardi:

Seu código não funciona porque a variável está sendo criada dentro de um escopo, no caso, o `public Form1()`, e está sendo chamada em outro escopo, no caso, o `button1_Click()`.

Para fazer isso, você teria que criar a variável em um escopo maior, ou ao menos, em um escopo em que os 2 tem acesso as variáveis. No seu caso, o `class Form1 : Form`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int c;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        c = 23;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"{c}");
    }
}
```

Perceba também que na string do `MessageBox`, eu imprimi a variável de uma maneira diferente, isso porque neste caso, em que o método pode receber mais de 1 parâmetro, ele pode considerar a variável como um. (Isso é só uma recomendação, e em minha opinião previne erros).

Comment: Apenas complementando: "imprimir a variável de uma maneira diferente", essa maneira se chama [Interpolação de Strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings).

Comment: Interessante, não sabia. @ThiagoLunardi

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o método **Format** da classe **String**.

Olhe o exemplo abaixo:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int c;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        c = 23;
    }    

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}", c));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Criar a variável fora de qualquer método irá resolver o problema:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
private int c;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    c = 23;
}    

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(c.ToString());
}
```

}

Você criou soua variável dentro de `public Form1()`, e só iria poder utiliza-lá dentro de `public Form1()`.
Se você criar ela dentro da sua classe e fora de qualquer método, você irá poder utiliza-lá em qualquer lugar dentro da sua classe.